# JQuery load page into div with styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I am trying to use `.load` so I can load an external page into a div on the current user's page. When I call `.load` , does it load the content and then style it with the current stylesheet defined in that page? If not how would I go about doing that? Example;

```
<head>
  <link ref="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="section">
    <h2>Say this div was loaded with .load after page loaded</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

If `.section` was loaded via `.load`, would the style be loaded of the current page and modify that div after it loaded or is it just the html that got loaded with no styling. If it is the latter, how would I style it without using `<style>` tags?

Comment: Did you try it and see what happens? You could answer your own questions that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime you alter the DOM in a way that causes a redraw (such as adding visible elements to the DOM), each element is checked against all the rules in the CSS style-sheets.

So to answer your question directly. Yes, the styles will be added to elements that are added to the DOM at anytime.

Comment: Any reason why it won't load the css but it will load the content? It only shows the text not the styled design but if I go to the page directly and add the link to my stylesheet, it looks perfect. Ideas?

Comment: Do you have a link I could check-out? That would make it easier to make a suggestion.

Comment: I am not allowed to post the link as my friend wants me to build this as a private beta site, he wants no-body to know what the site is about until it is launched.

Comment: I feel so retarted. I wrote this in php so I had \" instead of " so it wouldn't load the names of the divs. Good reason for them to not be styled. :p Sorry

Answer (score 1):

If the css is available on the page which contains `section` div then the styles will be applied after `load` renders the content. Also if the styles are part of the `load` response then also it will be rendered with styles applied.

If the styles are not available on the page and also you are not getting it in the load response then you have to explicitly get it using ajax or adding a link tag with appropriate stylesheet url into the page.

Answer (score 1):

Your style of the current page will apply to the content loaded via `.load`

Answer (score 1):

You can specify CSS in your main .css file, so when DOM is added, styles are taken from the main CSS file.